# reading file with xmlhttprequest results in error console entry

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I used the following code to read a file from javascript

```
    var filePath = "SBL_PROBES.txt";
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET",filePath,false);
    xmlhttp.send(null); 
    var fileContent = xmlhttp.responseText;
    var fileArray = fileContent.split('\n')
    var n = fileArray.length;
```

Things go fine and I can access the file contents from fileArray.  BUT an error appears on the firefox error console complaining about the contents of line 1 of the file.  I don't want the file interpreted by javascript or firefox, all I want are the contents which I parse with javascript.

The firefox console says

Error: syntax error
Source File: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Mike/Desktop/mustache/SBL_PROBES.txt
Line: 1, Column: 1
Source Code:
"title"        "Short Name"        "Long Name"           "Current","Maximum","Minimum","Day Max","Day Min"

**If I put `<blockquote> </blockquote`> in the file, the errors go away!**

What's going on and how can I fix it?

Do I need to do anything to close the file?  Will things be cleaned up when these vars go out of scope?

Comment: Complaining about what exactly, what is the error message? Anyways, it might be more feasible to use a framework for Ajax operations like jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ that irons out cross-browser inconsistencies

Comment: What is the error? Does the same happen in Chrome?

Comment: Where is this file located? You need to put in the full URL as the second parameter to `xmlhttp.open()`. Something like `xmlhttp.open("GET","http://mydomain.com/SBL_PROBES.txt",false)`;

Comment: My code works as expected, the file contents is returned.  The only thing wrong is the Firefox error console entry.Error: syntax error
Source File: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Mike/Desktop/mustache/SBL_PROBES.txt
Line: 1, Column: 1
Source Code:
"title"        "Short Name"        "Long Name"              "Current","Maximum","Minimum","Day Max","Day Min"

Comment: @whg: This is a synchronous request.  Do I have to wait?

Comment: If I put <blockquote> </blockquote> around the contents of the file, the error goes away.  It appears something is scanning my file as html?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
xmlhttp.overrideMimeType('text/plain');
```

By default it seems that local files are parsed with the XMLParser.

Comment: Yes it does fix it!  Thanks a lot!  I think I will leave the <blockquote></blockquote> tags in my files to mark the begin and end, it also makes them displayable.  My parser can ignore them.